# multiplying a hypergeometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, hypergeometric-function

We are able to calculate the value of the sum

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(a_1)_k(a_2)_k\dots(a_p)_k}{(b_1)_k(b_2)_k\dots(b_{p-1})_k}\cdot\frac{x^k}{k!}$, which equals the generalised hypergeometric function

${}_pF_q\left[\begin{matrix} 
a_1,a_2,\dots ,a_p  \\
b_1,b_2,\dots ,b_{p-1} 
\end{matrix}\quad;x\right]$.

Is it possible to calculate (or bound) $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(a_1)_k(a_2)_k\dots(a_p)_k}{(b_1)_k(b_2)_k\dots(b_{p-1})_k}\cdot\frac{x^k}{k!}\cdot k$ ?

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{(a_1)_k\cdots(a_{p})_k}{(b_1)_k\cdots(b_{q})_k}\frac{kx^k}{k!}$$
$$S=\frac{(a_1)_0\cdots(a_{p})_0}{(b_1)_0\cdots(b_{q})_0}\frac{0x^0}{0!}+\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{(a_1)_k\cdots(a_{p})_k}{(b_1)_k\cdots(b_{q})_k}\frac{kx^k}{k!}$$
$$S=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{(a_1)_k\cdots(a_{p})_k}{(b_1)_k\cdots(b_{q})_k}\frac{kx^k}{k!}$$
$$S=x\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{(a_1)_k\cdots(a_{p})_k}{(b_1)_k\cdots(b_{q})_k}\frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$
$$S=x\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{(a_1)_{k+1}\cdots(a_{p})_{k+1}}{(b_1)_{k+1}\cdots(b_{q})_{k+1}}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}$$
Note that $(a)_{n+1}=a\cdot(a+1)_n$. Thus,
$$S=x\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{a_1\cdots a_{p}}{b_1\cdots b_{q}}\frac{(a_1+1)_k\cdots(a_{p}+1)_k}{(b_1+1)_k\cdots(b_{q}+1)_k}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}$$
$$S=x\frac{a_1\cdots a_{p}}{b_1\cdots b_{q}}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{(a_1+1)_k\cdots(a_{p}+1)_k}{(b_1+1)_k\cdots(b_{q}+1)_k}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}$$
$$S=x\frac{a_1\cdots a_{p}}{b_1\cdots b_{q}}\;_pF_q\big(a_1+1,\dots,a_{p}+1;b_1+1,\dots,b_q+1;x\big)$$
And there you go.

Comment: Thank you so very much! You saved my day! So very nice of you.

If some literature would be on your mind for me to get in this calculations better, I would be also most thankful.

Comment: @Rafael You're very welcome

Comment: Would you know please some literature to improve in this calculations?

Comment: @Rafael Not really. I just started by looking at the series and going from there. Of course Wikipedia is always a good place to start. And then I would suggest Wolfram Function's site, and Wolfram Mathworld might have some good information. Just search "hypergeometric functions" on all of them. I'll tell you if I find anything good though.

Comment: Thank you very much. I searched also Google Scholar, Web of Science and Scopus, but was not satisfied with the results. 
If I include your previous solution in my PhD thesis, you will be cited as appropriate.

Comment: @Rafael It would be an honor to be cited in your PhD thesis. What are you doing your thesis on?

Comment: sure! my email is joverton2020@gmail.com

Comment: I send the email :)